# LSTM with multiple entries per time step

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm

I have a dataset with sales numbers for around 100 related products. Every day, the number of sales of each product is recorded along with other relevant information (what day of the week is it, is it a public holiday, what is the weather like etc. etc.).

So essentially this is a time series with daily entries, and I am thinking of pushing this through an LSTM.

My question is, how do I deal with the fact that I have multiple observations at every point in time?

```
Day         Product        Wheather        NumberSold
1 Jan       Meat           Sunny           15
1 Jan       Apples         Sunny           211
1 Jan       Fries          Sunny           5
...
1 Jan       Carrots        Cloudy          75
2 Jan       Meat           Cloudy          10
2 Jan       Apples         Cloudy          220
```

Answer (score -1):

```
model = Sequential()
#input_shape=(timesteps, features), features=inputsize 
model.add(LSTM(10,input_shape=(10,3))) 
model.add(Dense(1)) #one output
```

Comment: Can't see why this is a solution. Could you elaborate more?